# How to create following text using formula field?

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field

I want to create a text like `/lightning/n/Some_Page?c__recordId={!"+ objectfield1value +".Id}&c__docId="+ objectfield2value`

Whenever I am creating this it's automatically removing `"{!"` from the formula.

Comment: try with this.. "/lightning/n/Some_Page?c__recordId={" + "!" + "objectfield1value" + ".Id}&c__docId=" + "objectfield2value"

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi it worked! thank you for this simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

`"/lightning/n/Some_Page?c__recordId={" + "!" + objectfield1value + ".Id}&c__docId=" + objectfield2value`